# HxC floppy emulator on Amiga 1200, second virtual drive disappears after reboot

Tags: amiga, floppy-disk, amiga-1200, hxc

I've recently purchased a [HxC/Lotharek SD Card floppy drive emulator](http://hxc2001.free.fr/floppy_drive_emulator/). It's working well replacing DF0: but I'm seeing some odd behaviour with its emulation of DF1:.

On the first boot after power-up, the Amiga detects both DF0: and DF1:. But after a reboot, DF1: disappears.

The HxC does seem to be jumpered correctly (DS0 connected to drive A, DS1 connected to drive B) and there are no other drives, internal or external, connected.

What could be causing this problem?

---

**Update**: here is how I have configured the SD card.

1. Format as FAT32
2. Download the `QuickInstall_FloppyDiskImages.zip` file from the HxC website and unpack to a temporary location
3. Unpack the `SDHxCFE_Amiga.zip` file onto the SD card
4. Start the `HxCFloppyEmulator` app and go into the "SD HxC Floppy Emulator Settings" section
5. Click "Load config file" and select the HXCSDFE.CFG file off the SD card
6. Make these changes:

   1. Switch off "Load last loaded floppy" and "Enable auto boot mode" as I don't want these options at the moment
   2. Under "HFE file interfacemode", switch off "Auto" and manually select "Amiga"
   3. Verify that the SD HxC Floppy Emulator Interface setting has both Drive A and Drive B set to Amiga, and "2 drives emulation" switched on
7. Click "Save config file", and save to HXCSDFE.CFG on the SD card
8. Quit the app
9. Safely eject the SD card

Worringly, if I then restart the app and load the same config back in, my changes in 6.1 have been preserved, but my changes in 6.2 have gone back to the default of auto. In fact, if I read the [specification for the config file](http://hxc2001.com/download/floppy_drive_emulator/SDCard_HxC_Floppy_Emulator_HXCSDFE_CFG_file.pdf), it seems that these fields are not even part of the config file! So how can they be set?

Answer (score 6):

!! EDITED to reflect settings that I have tried on my Amiga to verify.

You need the following jumper settings to have HxC correctly emulate two drives

[image: Jumper settings]

This is a picture of my actual drive - it's the SD version in shape of regular floppy drive.

You can clearly see that ID0A and ID1B are set to ON. Nothing else.

You also need to configure the SD card correctly using the tool, it will save a file HXCSDFE.CFG that needs to go to the root of the card.

The image shows actual settings for two drives that I have just verified.

[image: Dual drive settings for HXC2001]

I have configured mine to use STARTUPA.HFE and STARTUPB.HFE images mapped to DF0 and DF1 respectively, simply renamed two of .HFE images I had on my SD card and booted the Amiga.

I actually haven't tried selecting images manually from the front panel - I don't know how to select image for DF1 - this is why I configured the startup HFE images.

Both drives work correctly with this configuration and lasted through several reboots with no issues.

I use WB3.9 on A1200 with Apollo with 060 @ 80MHz

Comment: Thanks Kuba but I have configured as you described and I still don't get DF1: detected after the first reboot. I have added some more detail to the question text which may be helpful.

Comment: @RichardDowner - I had some time on my hands, put the HXC drive in my A1200, configured it all from scratch to verify - the edited answer reflects the exact settings that work for me well.